# Cassandra node is getting stuck after nodetool decommission

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

I wish to decommission the Cassandra nodes as nodes need a version upgrade from 3.9 to 3.11. I log in to a particular node and execute the **nodetool decommission** command.

Most of the nodes are getting decommissioned from the cluster within few hours of operation but in some cases decommission is getting stuck and the node is not getting removed from the cluster, status/ state: UL. Initially, data is getting streamed across the different nodes and everything seems working fine, no error logs but after many hours it's there in the same state.

I intend to verify if decommission is successful through **nodetool netstats** and **nodetool status** whose output is below. In both the places, it says LEAVING

`nodetool netstats
Mode: LEAVING
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 62537724
Mismatch (Blocking): 921768
Mismatch (Background): 746828
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Dropped
Large messages                  n/a         0       44148788         0
Small messages                  n/a         1   238868718622       143
Gossip messages                 n/a         0       17713062         0`


`nodetool status
Datacenter: XXXX
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load    Tokens  Owns         Host ID                         Rack
UL  x.x.x.x  554.42 GiB  256    20.2% b2d0fe01-a0ce-4f41-b410-0dcf4aa7f5ef  rack1`

Again after restarting the Cassandra service it comes in UP/NORMAL state and I repeat the same process to decommission. For some of the node, it's getting decommissioned in a single try but for others, it's taking multiple tries to getting decommissioned successfully.

```
Machine Information: Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
Average Load on each node : ~500GB
```

What should be the next step to decommission this in a more efficient way?

Comment: is there anything in your logs? look for /var/log/cassandra/system.log

Comment: Logs say: Stream: All sessions completed

Comment: Why are you decommissioning nodes prior to an upgrade? Can't you upgrade in place?

Comment: I am decommissioning nodes prior to an upgrade because I want node data to be streamed to other nodes and upgraded node should get bootstrapped.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to decommission a node is to stop the node and run nodetool removenode  in another live node. This will assign the token ranges to other nodes and you can simply delete the data of the removed node. You can use nodetool removenode as long as you have replication factor>1, which means your data will be available in the other nodes also. In your case if you are removing multiple nodes then it depends on your replication factor value.

Comment: `removenode` should only be used in case `decommission` is not working. Also *do not* drain the node before decommission. Decomission actually disables the node even though the process is running. Also *do not* decommission multiple nodes at the same time.

Comment: @CarlosRolo, thanks for correcting, you are right about not to run nodetool drain.

Comment: Also, If you use nodetool removenode you will need the host id of the node you want to remove. You can get that by running nodetool status and copy / paste the host id of the node you wish to remove after the removenode option.

Comment: I have executed twice decommission process, second time I have removed decommissioned node from all servers seeds property. Even then it is receiving data and UL state is there. Please suggest .   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152353/cassandra-node-decommission-stuck-in-ul

Answer (score 1):

As per Datastax Support

Use these steps to get the node to decommission.

Step 1 - Restart Cassandra/DSE on the node.

Step 2 - Run nodetool decommission again and the node should be removed from the cluster as expected.

https://support.datastax.com/s/article/Node-stuck-in-LEAVING-state-after-being-decommissioned

Answer (score 0):

After decommission if node is not decommissioned then run nodetool assassinate .
It will forcefully remove the node .