# Cassandra node decommission stuck in UL

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra decommission is in UL state , today is 5th day of process. Streams completed within 3 days only, since then state is UL .

**Cluster details :**
5 nodes , RF 2 , all in same DC.

**Analysis :**

1. No streams in netstats command.
2. Data size of remaining nodes has increased.
3. I can see writing logs coming in the decommissioned node log file.
4. No error is there on any node of cluster.

**Please comment on :**

1. Is this decommission process completed, how to know more about it ?
2. If it is stuck , restarting a node will not help , because it will start from fresh.
3. Any specific property required to be added ?
4. Any specific line in log which can tell about decommissioning process?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the decommission process get stuck sometimes.  Here are the steps that I'd recommend:

1. Stop the node and `remove` it from the cluster.  This operation will also stream data in an attempt to prevent data loss.
2. Run a repair (on each node), and then check for data consistency.
3. If you notice data is missing, re-add the node, and retry the decommission process.